# Classification of compact connected Lie subgroup of $U(2)$

Tags: lie-groups, unitary-matrices

I am trying to find a way to classify all compact connected Lie group of unitary group $U(n)$. For simplicity, I would like to deal with $U(2)$. We have learned about using Dynkin diagram to classify compact simple Lie group. So, maybe I can do the same on $U(2)$. However, I don't know how to determine the simple root system of $U(2)$ explicitly, which is the cornerstone of Dynkin diagram. How someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to classify proper compact connected subgroups of $U(2)$ up to an isomorphism, the list will be quite small: $SU(2), U(1)$ and $U(1)\times U(1)$. As for the root system, it is of type $A_1$ (although, since your group is not semisimple, it is really the root system of $SU(2)$). As for subgroups of $U(n)$, once $n$ get's large, you are out of luck. You can classify maximal closed connected subgroups though.